# Query on multiple tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create a query to pull data from 2 different tables in BQ. Both of them contain the same schema. Is it possible to do something like this in BQ?

```
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([567.ga_sessions_],[1234.ga_sessions_],DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -2, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'))) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Table wildcard functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#tablewildcardfunctions) are a convenient way in BigQuery Legacy SQL to query data from a specific set of tables.
`Specific Set` here is actually `Dataset`.
So if your tables are spread across different datasets - you will need to [UNION ALL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#comma_as_union_all) subsets that belong to different datasets.
In your case it will be union of two sets:

```
SELECT <fields> 
FROM 
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([567.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -2, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY')),
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([1234.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -2, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'))
```

> added to address latest comment:

```
SELECT
  Domains,
  DATE,
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(fullvisitorid) AS UniqueCustomers,
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    "SiteA" AS Domains,
  FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE([12342.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -2, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'))),
(
  SELECT
    *,
    "SiteB" AS Domains,
  FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE([12311.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -2, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'))),
GROUP BY
  DATE,
  Domains
```

Comment: Does the below query make sense to you? 

SELECT Date, EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(fullvisitorid) AS UniqueCustomers, FROM ( SELECT *, "SiteA" AS Domains, FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([12342.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -2, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'))), FROM ( SELECT *, "SiteB" AS Domains, FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([12311.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -2, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'))), GROUP BY Date, Domains

Comment: no, it doesn't. you should remove third (counting from top) FROM

Comment: But i am trying to group my data by domains, i would need to have the FROM clause 4 times in this statement no?

Comment: sure. you just need to remove extra from as I mentioned in my previous comment. otherwise you will get syntax error. see addition to answer.

Comment: thanks for the additional query, but i am not able to see the domain names in the table. Is there something wrong with the query?

Comment: if you want to see Domains you should just add them to select statement! right?

Comment: I actually fixed this issue and was able to comment and you replied.thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the _TABLE_SUFFIX pseudo column in Standard SQL.

```
SELECT ...
FROM `myproject.567.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY)) AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", CURRENT_DATE())
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
FROM `myproject.1234.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY)) AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", CURRENT_DATE())
```

In Legacy SQL, something like this:

```
SELECT
  <desired fields>
FROM
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([myproject.1234], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -2, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY')),
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([myproject.567], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -2, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'))
```

Comment: I used the ... since I don't know the table schema. Can you please try with the actual list of desired fields?

Comment: Is there a way to do this using Legacy SQL?

Comment: Yesterday, I edited the original answer to add a legacy sql variant.

Answer (score 0):

For Legacy SQL, use the comma as a union operator to union two separate TABLE_DATE_RANGEs, like so:

```
FROM 
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([1234.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -2, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY')),
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([567.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -2, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'))
```